# how to find out the candidate key in relational database design

Tags: database, relational-database

I was given relation R(A,B,C,D) and the set of functional dependencies {A->B, B->C}. The attribute D isn't listed anywhere in the set of functional dependencies.

How any there be a candidate key without having D in the set of functional dependencies?

Comment: If you know the basics of relational databases, there's nothing at all unclear about what the OP is asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every database textbook I've seen includes at least one pencil-and-paper algorithm to determine all the candidate keys for a given relation. Look through your textbook.

Speaking informally, an attribute that's not part of any functional dependency must be part of *every* candidate key.

In your original question, given R(ABCD) and F(A->B, B->C) you'd add the trivial functional dependency D->D to F. The only candidate key is AD.

In your comment, given R(ABCD) and F(A->B, A->C, AC->D), the only candidate key is A.

Comment: what would be the candidate key if the functioanl dependency set is like :

Comment: what would be the candidate key if the functioanl dependency set is like : A->B, A->C Ac->D ...Now clearly One candidate key is AC..can I include AD as a candidate key ..actually this is my doubt.

Comment: For R(ABCD) and the set of functional dependencies {A->B, A->C, AC->D}, AC is not a candidate key. Neither is AD.